# Discord js using message id in Embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know that you can "link" users and Channel with the prefix "@/#" in Embed Messages. But can you use a message id to send a user directly to a message when pressing on it? Is there a prefix to do this?
For context: I got an FAQ channel and would like to send a user directly to the point he needs in the FAQ.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with just the message ID, but you can use the message link. In your embed field you can use simple Markdown syntax:

```markdown
[display text](http://discord.com/channels/123456789/987654321/123456789)
```

You'll need to replace the URL with your message link.

Comment: Well it sends you to the message! But... It displays the link and thats not so smooth to have in my embed... Is there a way to hide the URL? I know from webdesign where you can add the link to a text with "href" etc. Is there anything like this in discordjs?
Oh yeah and thanks for the fast answer! :D

Comment: What I put above should work for that, but only within an embed field unfortunately

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/me0OqPr here's an example of how you could use it